# Question about a result in an article by Erdős on Ramsey theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I'm finding very hard to understand a result by Erdős on a paper from 1947 titled "Some Remarks on the Theory of Graphs" that states:

> Define $A(n)$ as the greatest integer such that given any graph $G$ of $n$ vertices, either it or its complementary graph contains a complete subgraph of order $A(n)$. Then for $3\leq A(n)$
>
> $\frac{log\ n}{2log\ 2}<A(n)<\frac{2log\ n}{log\ 2}$
>
> The proof follows immediately from Theorem I. $(4^{A(n)}>n,\ 2^{A(n)/2}<n)$

Theorem I refers to the main result of the article which gives some elementary bounds for Ramsey numbers. (I adapted the notation so that it resembles the more modern one).

> **Theorem I.**
>  Let $k\ge3$. Then $2^{k/2}<R(k, k)\le {2k-2\choose k-1}<4^{k-1} $

Then, an obvious way of applying this result to the first statement would be if $R(A(n), A(n)) = n$.

But why is that true? I can't seem to point out why.

Also, is $A(n)$ some sort of inverse Ramsey number?

Comment: No it's not true that $R(A(n)) = n$ (simply because $R(k)$ is a fast-growing sequence, so it can't take all values). But it is true that $R(A(n)) \le n < R(A(n)+1)$, and that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the observation! Why are those inequalities true?

Comment: By definition, $A(n)$ is the largest integer $k$ such that $R(k) \le n$, so $R(k) \le n < R(k+1)$.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Thanks I already edited it.